# API Swift 4 call with Authentication. Simple. but stuck

Tags: ios, swift4

Finding a simple answer to this has me finally asking.

What do I need to do/add to this to send the authentication with the url call?
I'm all about it but just can't see the solution.

Set up the url with the necessary info, and make the call.
This is the Curl call:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.jsecoin.com/v1.7/balance/auth/0/ \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: JSE API Key"
```

Sample response:

```
{
 "success": 1, 
 "notification": "Your balance is 99 JSE",
 "balance": 99
 }
```

This is my code snippet to do this in Swift 4, XCode 9.xx iOS 11.4, but I can't work out how to add in the authorization.

```
 func makeGetCall() {
    // Set up the URL request
    //let todoEndpoint: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"


    let todoEndpoint: String = "https://api.jsecoin.com/v1.7/balance/auth/0/"

    //-H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""

    guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ]

    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
```

This returns,

```
The todo is: ["notification": API Balance Failed: User API key credentials  could not be matched, "fail": 1]
```

Could not get todo title from JSON

Comment: have you add "Authorization:" text before your key in header?

Comment: try to set "Authorization" header in URLRequest not URLSessionConfiguration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Header parameter in URLRequest not in URLSessionConfiguration

Here is your solution

```
func makeGetCall() {
    // Set up the URL request
    //let todoEndpoint: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"


    let todoEndpoint: String = "https://api.jsecoin.com/v1.7/balance/auth/0/"

    //-H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\""

    guard let url = URL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)


    urlRequest.setValue(signature, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)



    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on /todos/1")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, this is showing "use of unresolved identifier 'request'" in both places, also 'signature' is unknown

Comment: Great. That got it. I could not see how to include the header detail. The 'signature' is actually my API key, so I put my 'apiKey' there and it now works. Nice. Thank you. Marked as answer

Comment: @HarryMcGovern welcome. signature is just placeholder